# Django templates - not displaying dynamic images

Tags: django, image, django-templates

I've read other questions about images, but I still couldn't resolve my issue : ( It's probably something basic as I'm new to django.

so I have model Example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "examples/")
```

and I would like to display it in template. As a view I use generic detailView. This is   part related to image of a template:

```
<p>Image: <img src="{{ example.image.url }}"/></p>
```

I changed my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nicpon/Dokumenty/aplikacje/images/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

and at this point site is diplayed without image (at it's place there's that square which is shown when image couldn't be displayed)

now I changed also urls.py :`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', url(r'^images/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})),
```

but that resulted in error: "'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'" on every page.

Edit:
when I put {{ example.image.url }} outside img tag it shows  /images/exapmles/specific_image.jpg
and directory to that image on my computer is /home/nicpon/Dokumenty/aplikacje/images/examples/specific_image.jpg

And the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/examples/sepcific_image.jpg

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'example',
 'registration')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  67.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  531.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  420.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /images/examples/specific_image.jpg
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

Comment: Put `{{ example.image.url }}` somewhere outside `<img>` and look what does it display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing something like this is your settings.py:

```
MEDIA_SERVER_URL = 'http://www.example.com/'
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_SERVER_URL, 'images/')
```

and then do

```
src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ example.image.url }}"
```

Also check for permissions:

1. Media Directory (/home/nicpon/Dokumenty/aplikacje/images/): Should allow read by your webserver (eg: chgrp www-data images)
2. Your webserver should be configured to handle media serving appropriately. Ideally a separate media server can be used, but you should check the respective URLs if you are having django serve the media (as seems to be the case from your urls.py)